# How to change layout of an activity automatically on day change ? any simple way?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alarms

In my application I want to change my layout on day change ie if I am using my app continuously than after 12:00 am the Current activity layout should automatically change. I want know if there is there any simple way to change layout on day change ? 
Currently I am changing layout using alarm but this method usage more battary power So If any one have any better Idea ?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html).

1. In your Activity's onStart(), check to see if the new day has occurred. If so, call your layout change method.
2. In any case, set a Timer with a TimerTask that will be run the next time 12am occurs. In that TimerTask, call your layout change method.

Comment: Ok in my app there are 5-7 activity using base activity. and i have to use Timer in every activity or in base activity?

Comment: What do you mean by base activity? Do you mean you have 5-7 activities that extend a base activity? If so, you can put the timer in the base activity. Remember to clear the timer in onStop() though.

Comment: thanks and one more Que that how could i know my current activity and how could i call layout change method. because they are define in activities.

Comment: You know the current activity because your code runs in onStart().

Comment: But timer is in base activity and layout change method is in every activity.so how could i call layout change method.

Comment: You can call your layout change method if your activities implement an interface containing that layout change method. Or, the method could be defined as an abstract method in the base class.

Answer (score 0):

on your main activity, you can check days and set the layout you want

Comment: ya i did this but problem is when day changes.